# Why does $\cos(-\pi)=-1$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm looking for some explanation of the following equation:

> $$\cos(-\pi)=-1$$

I'm not sure how this works out.

Comment: You can intuitively think of cos(theta) as the x-coordinate of the point on the unit circle which corresponds to the angle theta. On the unit circle, the angle -pi corresponds to the point (-1,0). The x-coordinate of (-1,0) is -1, and so cos(-pi) = -1

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we just consider the ratio of sides of a triangle definition of cosine (i.e. $\cos(\theta) = \frac{adjacent}{hypotenuse})$, we can think intuitively about why cosine would have this value. By fixing one vertex of a right triangle at $(0,0)$, we can form a right triangle with a specified angle of $\theta$ by rotating the vector $<1, 0>$ counterclockwise by $\theta$ (where $-\theta$ indicates clockwise rotation). Then we form the triangle by taking the end of the rotated vector as a vertex, and its projection onto the x-axis as the 3rd vertex.

If we consider a rotation by $-\pi$, the "triangle" consists of the vertices $(0,0), (-1, 0), (-1, 0))$ and the sides $S_1: (0,0), (-1, 0)$; $S_2: (-1, 0), (-1,0)$; and $S_3: (-1,0), (0,0)$. The "opposite" side, $S_2$ has length $0$, the "adjacent" side, $S_1$ has length $1$, and the "hypotenuse," $S_3$ length $-1$, and thus $\cos(-\pi) = \frac{1}{-1} = -1$.

Alternative definitions of $\cos$ can give us different ways of thinking about it. For example, if we define

$$\cos(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

the sum converges to -1 when we take $x = -\pi$

Comment: What are the vertices of this "right triangle?"  And why is the angle $-\pi <0$?

Comment: The vertices (considered as coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^2$ would be $(0,0), (-1,0), (-1,0)$. Fixing a vertex at $(0,0)$ and rotating the vector $<1,0>$ counterclockwise by $\theta$ (where $-\theta$ indicates clockwise rotation by $\theta$) will produce the final two vertices at the tip of the rotated vector and its projection onto the x-axis to form a right triangle. I put "right triangle" in quotation marks in this case because the full rotation of $-\pi$ creates a side length of $0$, which may be objectable.

Comment: I see why my initial explanation was sub-par though it was fine in my head.... I'll work on rewording it